# Amplifier as an error detetctor

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, current, resistors

[image]

In this diagram, can the op-amp be used as the error detector? Can it compare the load position to the input position at CX and produce an error signal?

Comment: What op-amp in the picture above? What do you precisely mean by *error detector*?

Comment: Like in the picture, the control transformer(CT) is the error detector as it compares the difference between the load position and the CX position an produces an error signal which is amplified by the amplifier. Can the Op-amp however do this too? Like take in both signals and produce the error signal?

Comment: The CT is taking in a mechanical response and "merging" it with the output of CX. Does that sound like it is compatible with the inputs off an op-amp?

Comment: You have shown a block diagram of the control system. The implementation of some of this functionality may use an op-amp. Without knowing about system specifics it would be difficult to give any answer other than 'maybe'.

Comment: No. The CT does that as per comment to your other duplicate question.

Comment: @Brian Drummond can the CT be considered as an inductive position sensor?

Comment: One of the CT's inputs is shaft position, so ... yes.